# rst2pdf installed how can I obtain a .pdf from .rst file?

Tags: rst-mode

as I already told I've installed rst2pdf docutil, but if I run

```
 M-x rst-compile-pdf-preview
```

I get a quick message saying that Ive to use `C-c C-c C-p`
but, entering that, I obtain

```
You can run the command ‘rst-compile-pdf-preview’ with C-c C-c C-p
```

and if I made that I do not obtain nothing
What I still have to do?

Thank you

Renato

Answer (score 2):

rst2pdf convert the document to a PDF file and launch a preview program.

Maybe emacs doesn't find the preview program (maybe you don't have xpdf installed or not in your path)

Comment: it's like the compilation doesen't start. I just receive the message "You can run the command ‘rst-compile-pdf-preview’ with C-c C-c C-p". but if I also type it I have no feedback. The file.pdf is no produced.

Comment: Do `C-x b *Messages*` to visit your `*Messages*` buffer and see if there are any error messages that might help you.

Comment: Mark set
Beginning of buffer [50 times]
End of buffer [32 times]
Beginning of buffer [36 times]
<nil> <wheel-left> is undefined
ren.rst has auto save data; consider M-x recover-this-file
Making completion list...
You can run the command ‘rst-compile-pdf-preview’ with C-c C-c C-p
End of buffer [14 times]
Beginning of buffer [7 times]
I cannot read anythings bad here. Do you?

Comment: Nope - you'll have to dig deeper...

Comment: I've never told that I'm working on Mac Osx 12.5 . Could it be important?

Comment: If you launch `xpdf`, do you have a graphical interface?

Comment: yes, Xpdfreader is open

Comment: yes, Xpdfreader is open
But, back in emacs, I've opened two buffer:README.rst and *MESSAGES* to see what happen: if I give C-c C-c C-p or if run M-x rst-compile-pdf-previw, the *MESSAGES* buffer don't show nothing, like the command were not issued

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably incomplete or incorrect setup of the `rst` utilities (and possibly `xpdf`).

So forget about Emacs for the moment. Open a terminal running a shell and type this command:

```shell
rst2pdf myfile.rst myfile.pdf
```

where `myfile.rst` is your input file. Did that produce a PDF? If not, you have to fix that first: do not go on until you can complete this step successfully.

When you have produced a PDF successfully, then try to preview it with this command:

```shell
xpdf myfile.pdf
```

Did that show you the PDF? If not, you have to fix this first: do not go on until you can preview the PDF.

Once both of these steps are successful, then, and only then, you can go back to Emacs: do `C-x C-f myfile.rst` and then do `C-c C-c C-p`. The command that is executed under the covers will be similar to this:

```shell
rst2pdf /tmp/rst/myfile.rst /tmp/rst_elikNHBA.pdf && xpdf /tmp/rst_elikNHBA.pdf ; rm /tmp/rst_elikNHBA.pdf
```

which is basically a combination of what I showed above. But note that the PDF is produced in a temporary file which is *removed* after the preview.

**EDIT**: The OP states in a comment that the two steps above go well, but when he visits the file in Emacs and does `C-c C-c C-p` nothing happens. So we have to turn to debugging what Emacs is doing.

In the buffer of `myfile.rst`, is the major mode reported as `rst-mode`? You can check if that is the case, with `C-h v major-mode` but be careful to do it in the correct buffer, that of `myfile.rst`. It should say:

```
Its value is ‘rst-mode’
Original value was ‘fundamental-mode’
Local in buffer myfile.rst; global value is fundamental-mode
```

Does it?
If not, either your emacs does not include the `rst.el` library or your `auto-mode-alist` does not know that files with the `rst` suffix should be in `rst-mode`. Neither of these is likely
but you never know. BTW, please add the Emacs version to your question: do `M-x emacs-version` to find it. You should always include the version in any question you ask in the future.

In that same buffer, do `C-h k C-c C-c C-p` - it should say:

```
 C-c C-c C-p runs the command rst-compile-pdf-preview (found in
rst-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘rst.el’.
```

Does it?

If both of those are correct, it should all work: the file should be compiled into a (temporary) PDF file and `xpdf` should open it for viewing; when you close `xpdf`, the PDF file is removed. Note that while `xpdf` is open, the PDF file still exists, so you can sneak in from a terminal and copy it somewhere else for safekeeping - it's only when `xpdf` is closed that the PDF file is removed.

If it still does not work, then the only recourse I can suggest is to run the command under a debugger to see what's going on.

Also, if nothing happens, take another look at the `*Messages*` buffer and see if there is anything of note in there. I would expect either success or an error message.

I should also mention that I've tried all this on my system and it works fine.

Comment: the first steps goes well, xpdf myfile.pdf show with xpdfreader the file
But when on emacs I type C-x C-f myfile.rst and the C-c C-c C-p, nothing appens

Comment: Added some suggestions for debugging the Emacs side, since the system side seems OK.

Comment: emacs 28.1. When I run

Comment: - emacs 28.1

- C-c C-c C-p runs the command rst-compile-pdf-preview (found in
rst-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘rst.el’.
It is bound to C-c C-c C-p.
(rst-compile-pdf-preview)
Convert the document to a PDF file and launch a preview program.
I have the suspect that xpdf is not binded to emacs.
on my mac previw program is the defaul program to open .pdf.
How can I be sure that when I type C-C C-c C-p the command to create a .pdf are give to emacs?

Comment: What does `C-h v rst-pdf-program` say? It should be `xpdf` by default, but maybe it's different in your setup?

Comment: rst-pdf-program is a variable defined in ‘rst.el’.

Its value is "xpdf"

Program used to preview PDF files.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
So, this show that my idea is not correct isn't it?

Comment: I give up - I don't know what could be wrong. Maybe you can find an experienced emacs user nearby (maybe at a local university?) and see if they can come up with a solution.

Comment: Can I check if the result of command: "C-x C-f myfile.rst and then do C-c C-c C-p
The command that is executed under the covers" is similar to this?

rst2pdf /tmp/rst/myfile.rst /tmp/rst_elikNHBA.pdf && xpdf /tmp/rst_elikNHBA.pdf ; rm /tmp/rst_elikNHBA.pdf

Comment: The way I got that command was by running `C-c C-c C-p` after I instrumented `rst-compile-pdf-preview` with [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html) - you can try that but it does require some experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138312/discussion-between-renatop-and-nickd).

Answer (score 0):

I've finaly solved the situation.
I've installed a VM (Manjaro) and installed all the tool chain: emacs,python3 was already installed, docutils, rst2pdf,Xpdfreader. created my .rst file (emacs recognised the file type) and finaly with C-c C-c C-c O've created the .html and with C-c C-c C-p emacs has created the .pdf that was opened with Xpdfreader and the I safe it.

I made the same path on mac osx 12.5 but before I've removed the old installation of python 3 and installed a brand new python version. I think the prob was there.
thank you to all that gave me indications and suggestion

Renato